# iOS cancel (void)-execution and dismiss ViewController

Tags: ios, methods, background-process, uiviewanimation

I want to cancel a long running calculation method and dismiss the ViewController when app is send to background.

Details:
After button action in MainViewController a new ResultViewController is shown and a long running calculation method is started in the ViewDidLoad method.
The calculation method is running on the main thread which is totally fine.

For the case the app is going to background I want to prevent that the app is killed due to the not finished calculation method. I set up the applicatinDidEnterBackground notification which could be used in the ResultViewController but I don't know how to cancel the running calculation method and to dismiss the ResultViewController.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and a ***long running*** calculation method is started in the ViewDidLoad method. The calculation method is running on the main thread which is totally fine.

Honesty, I doubt that this can be labelled as 'fine'.

Proper solution would be to move these calculations to background thread and execute them asynchronously.

If you block main thread for too long (like in this case) then you won't even know that app is going to be put to the background - notification about that won't be processed by the app's main queue since you consume all of its resources. Watchdog will just kill your application since it cannot process `applicatinDidEnterBackground` notification within a reasonable amount of time (approximately 7-8 seconds).

---

Edit (in response to question in comment)

You may want to check out how to implement `NSOperation` and how to use `NSOperationQueue`. Good resource for that is for example [this site.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)

What I'm telling you is to get general idea how cancellation of operations work - especially usage of `isCancelled` property, which is checked in critical sections of operation (and is used to stop computations). You don't have to implement NSOperation in your case (unless you want - it may be a good exercise ;-) ) but if you create some class that is processing data, and you add a method like `cancel` in it, then you can imitate `NSOperation's` behavior in your code.

Comment: deekay, thanks for you answer. I didn't think about that fact that the notification is blocked. I'll try to change that.

Comment: Hello Deekay again, it looks like you know more about that business. Could you give me more details to put an task in the background but be able to kill it when `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

Comment: Thanks, I looked up `NSOperation` already but I need to get more comfortable with it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hello deekay, I just want to thank you again to put me on the right track. I wasn't realizing that I went into trouble with doing all that big calculation on the main thread. It took me quite long time and some annoying shots but I got it now and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to hear so! :-)